# Is there any way to identify item moved to specific iteration in TFS?

Tags: tfs

New items created can be easily found out by having query created on "Created Date" field. Is there any way to identify TFS items whose iteration have been changed from lets say iteration 11 to iteration 12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know the items under a specific iteration, there is a filed called **Iteration Path**, you can directly specify the Iteration such as below picture.

[image]

Update

---

There is also a `@CurrentIteration` under Iteration Path. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2015-mar-10-vso

However, you may have to use **TFS2015** and  **VS 2015** or **VS 2013 Update 5**. For TFS2012, I'm afraid that there is not such a macro.  See [Is there a TFS query macro for the current iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090345/is-there-a-tfs-query-macro-for-the-current-iteration)

Comment: This one will give me current items in said iteration, it won't let me know the movement of new/existing items to current iteration.

Comment: There is also a @CurrentIteration . https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2015-mar-10-vso However, you may have to use TFS2015 and  VS 2015 or VS 2013 Update 5. For TFS2012, I'm afraid that there is not such a macro.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090345/is-there-a-tfs-query-macro-for-the-current-iteration

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get this information via query for now. If you do need these information, you can get it by [TFS API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet). The workflow would be get all the workitems under "Iteration 12" by WIQL and then check the history of these workitems and record the workitems which the previous iteration path is "Iteration 11".